# Autodetect remote running Java processes on Java Mission Control

Tags: java, jmx, jmc

I'm trying to discover remote running processes on Java Mission Control.
So that, I'm using the following attributes to start the JVM:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=50099 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=50099 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.autodiscovery=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jdp.name=MyCluster/MyJVM Teste \
-Dcom.sun.management.jdp.address=224.0.23.178 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jdp.port=50099
```

In Java Mission Control, the JDP preferences are set to:

- Multicast group to join: 224.0.23.178
- Multicast port: 50099
- Heart Beat Timeout(s): 12

But it is not working for me. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you might have read http://hirt.se/blog/?p=388
Marcus mentions TTL, and refers to the command line reference (which I currently can't find, will try to find it..),
but I would believe the sysprop would be:
-Dcom.sun.management.jdp.ttl=(default is 1)

If you know your client and server are on different subnets, this might be worth setting to something higher. (This requires the router(s) to have multicast enabled)

I'm not sure that using the same port for JDP and JMX is a good idea (it might work, I just don't know..). This could also be worth changing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Klara. I found the command line reference and changed it to higher values (32, 64). I also removed RMI port, but it still doesn't work. The router has multicast enabled.

Comment: Does it work if you try starting a jvm with the same flags on your client machine?

Comment: It appears only under 'Local'.

Comment: What if you run it locally, but revert back to the default jdp  port? I'll try to ask the JDP whiz in our team to see if he has any ideas.

Comment: What versions of JVM and JMC are you using?

Comment: JDK 1.8.0_20
JMC 5.4.0

Comment: You should be able to see the JVM under Discovered(JDP) (if you enable the tree view). Some setting on your machine is affecting this then, will try to find out which settings/permissions could be required..

Comment: Got this link from our JDP whiz, relevant in case you run on Linux and haven't set up multicast/broadcast locally ... http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.multicast.html

Comment: Thanks, Klara. That will be usefull. But when I run locally (on Windows) it also doesn't work.

Comment: If you add the -verbose flag when starting your local server jvm, do you see any printouts like this?:                                                                                            [Loaded sun.management.jdp.JdpController from c:\java\8u20-b26\jre\lib\rt.jar]

Comment: I'm wondering if setting -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true on the server jvm would make any difference.

Comment: Starting the JVM with -verbose flag didn't show anything related to sun.management.jdp.JdpController. -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true didn't make any difference.

Comment: I forgot the -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=false. It's too similar to -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false and I wasn't able to see the difference.

Comment: Did that help? I thought registry.ssl defaulted to false?